# Suppress windows repositioning on resolution change (WM_DISPLAYCHANGE)

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, user-interface

Is there any way to disable a feature where windows get automatically repositioned by the OS when I change resolution/unplug monitors? Basically I already have some code to handle window placements (with some custom logic) and it conflicts with OS when monitor configuration changes.
The worst thing is that Windows may decide to reposition windows sometimes before sometimes after WM_DISPLAYCHANGE (if it was always before I could have simply called my own repositioning function when I get WM_DISPLAYCHANGE).

Comment: The purpose of this feature is to ensure that windows remain accessible. If you had a window positioned on a secondary monitor, and then that monitor was removed, how would a normal user access that window? If you suppress this, how are you going to handle that problem?